# Запуск сценария оболочки UNIX

Tags: unix, ubuntu

Доброго времени суток. Пользоваться Ubuntu (11.10) начал относительно недавно, поэтому полный чайник в этом. Прошу помощи.

Есть файл, сценарий оболочки UNIX. Если дважды кликнуть на него, он открывается в блокноте.Зашел в **Свойства** - **Права** и в строке **Выполнение** пытался поставить галочку на "**Разрешить исполнения файла как программы**". Она ставится, и через пол секунды пропадает. Т.е. во вкладке **Права** я не могу изменить абсолютно ничего, а запустить этот файл очень надо.Как быть?

Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Можно из командной строки

```
cd местоchmod +x скрипт.sh./скрипт.sh
```

Либо зайти в проводник, затем Права -> Параметры -> Поведение и отметить опцию "Запускать исполняемые текстовые файлы при открытии". Если у вас есть права на изменение прав доступа к файлу, делаете так, как вы описали, затем клик по файлу.